# getting error while creating emr cluster using cli commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-emr

Commands to create EMR

aws emr create-cluster --auto-scaling-role EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole --termination-protected --region us-east-1 --name my-name --release-label emr-5.2.1 --applications Name=Hadoop Name=Hive Name=Pig Name=Hue Name=Spark --service-role EMR_DefaultRole --tags ASV=CI OwnerContact=myid CMDBEnvironment=myenv --ec2-attributes 'KeyName=mykey,InstanceProfile=EMR_EC2_DefaultRole,SubnetId=subnet-121212,EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup=sg-121212,AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups=[my security grps],EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup=sg-xxxxx,AdditionalSlaveSecurityGroups=[sg-xxxxx,sg-xxxx],ServiceAccessSecurityGroup=sg-xxxx' --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m3.xlarge --log-uri s3://mybucket/ --enable-debugging --security-configuration COF-Encrypted --bootstrap-actions 'Path=s3://mybucket/code/tools/deployment/centrify-join.sh,Name=Centrify,Args=[dqa.capitalone.com,QAWS_ENVNP_ODEM_CG]' --additional-info '{ '\''ami64'\'':'\''ami-8d40c69b'\'', '\''amiHvm64'\'': '\''ami-8d40c69b'\'', '\''customAMI'\'': true, '\''hadoopConfigurationVersion'\'': '\''4.0'\'', '\''instanceAwsClientConfiguration'\'': { '\''proxyPort'\'': xxxx, '\''proxyHost'\'': '\''myproxy'\'' } }' --output text

Am getting the error mentioned below

Unknown options: --auto-scaling-role,EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole,--security-configuration,COF-Encrypted

Can anyone help out in this regard.

Comment: whats your aws cli version ? did you check the doc for this command (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-cluster.html)  the options are not there.

Comment: both the options are there .

Comment: in this version yes indeed so check your aws cli version and the doc for your version, those options are pretty new

Comment: Thanks Henri for the update , I am creating cluster using jenkins job . It was working for me last night , but starting today I got this error.